# Is there an automatic way to clean up a mesh that was modeled with the subdivision modifier?

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface, retopology

Basically as part of my workflow, to "clean-up" the mesh, that I've been modeling while the subdiv modifier is active is to periodically apply it, then delete all the edges that were added in to get a cleaner version of the base mesh. This provides excellent results but is very time consuming.

I've tried options like the decimate modifier with the un-subdivide option, but it doesn't do a very good job and I'm left with an unusable mesh. I've also tried the smooth modifiers, but again, it doesn't provide a nice clean mesh that retains the same structure as the original vs if I had manually applied the subdiv, then deleted the added edges.

Is there some option I'm missing that could eliminate the time consuming nature of this workflow?

Comment: There are additional Remesh options (voxel and quad) under the _Object Data Properties_ tab. Try seeing if one of those suits your purpose (I suggest starting with Quadriflow, choosing the same relative number of faces as your mesh already has, or slightly fewer). Remember, you can do this after a "messy" decimate operation to change the topology back to quads. - just don't go too crazy with how many faces you try to remove.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I just tested those out and they appear to change the edge flow substantially, which is one thing I'm trying to avoid. Basically I want to keep the edges the same, just "move" them into the place they would be if the subdivision was applied, but without having to add new edges (almost as if i was applying a subdivision level 0 where it applies, then unapplies, but keeps the updated positions)

Comment: How about this: duplicate the object. Then make sure only the duplicated object has a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and remove it from the original object. Now, add a *Shrinkwrap* modifier to the original object and use the duplicate as the target for this modifier. Finally, apply the *Shrinkwrap* modifier and delete the duplicated object. That's it. No need to apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and clean up the mesh.